# Removing strings on the basis of number of characters in R

Tags: r

If I have a dataframe like this,

```
V1 V2 V3
1  2  abchd00ajnsf
2  3  urr0sfj0s000
3  4  00000000ab00
4  5  ajauiauiajoi
.................
```

I wish to remove those rows from the dataframe in which in the third column, the number of alphabets is less than 3.
For example, the third row will be removed since the number of characters in its string is less than 3.
How can I do it in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove all the numbers with `gsub`, then take the number of characters with `nchar`

```
df[!nchar(gsub("[0-9]+", "", df[[3]])) < 3L,]
#   V1 V2           V3
# 1  1  2 abchd00ajnsf
# 2  2  3 urr0sfj0s000
# 4  4  5 ajauiauiajoi
```

Or equivalently

```
df[nchar(gsub("[0-9]+", "", df[[3]])) > 2L,]
```

**Added :** You can also do this with `grepl` using the regular expression `(\\D.*){3}`.

```
df[grepl("(\\D.*){3}", df[[3]]), ]
#   V1 V2           V3
# 1  1  2 abchd00ajnsf
# 2  2  3 urr0sfj0s000
# 4  4  5 ajauiauiajoi
```